# How to modify XML node value?

Tags: android, xml, xmlnode

I am new developer in java application. I would like to modify an XML file node value. I have used an xml file for modify as follows

```
  <staff id="2">
       <firstname>yong</firstname>
       <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
       <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
       <salary>2000000</salary>
       <age>28</age>
   </staff>
```

in above xml I would like to change salary value as 345375. For this modification I have written code as follows

```
 try{
     DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("/sdcard/myxml.xml"));

    //Get the staff element by tag name directly
     Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff").item(0);
    //loop the staff child node
     NodeList list = nodes.getChildNodes();

     for (int i =0; i<list.getLength();i++){
         Node node = list.item(i);

         //get the salary element, and update the value
         if("salary".equals(node.getNodeName())){
             node.setNodeValue("345375");        
         }
     }
}
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if I use this way that value not modifying salary.

How can I modify an XML node value?

Comment: Seems right to me. Did you save the file before terminating the program? It might be getting discarded.

Comment: could u please say how to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to realize that `node.setValue()` is modifying the representation that is stored *in memory*. Knowing that, then you just need to figure out how to write that output to disk. See [this](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-3), for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
node.Text = "Enter your value here"; //This will work
```