# How to save & update the values in xml file?

Tags: android, saxparser

I am reading a xml file from the SD card. Here I want to change the values of the XML file and I want to save the file to the sd card..

My code is like below.... Please guide me how to save XML file to the sd card after updating the values..

```
public void modifyNodeval(){
        try{
         DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("/sdcard/sss.xml"));

        //Get the staff element by tag name directly
         Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Employee").item(0);
        //loop the staff child node
         NodeList list = nodes.getChildNodes();

         for (int i =0; i<list.getLength();i++){
             Node node = list.item(i);

             //get the salary element, and update the value
             if("Emp_Name".equals(node.getNodeName())){
                 node.setNodeValue("795796");
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[how to modify xml node value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571728/how-to-modify-xml-node-value)

Answer (score 1):

This method writes a DOM document to a file on the SD Card
If you want to test this in the emulator, make sure your AVD image is setup with an SD Card image (done during image creation).

```
public static void writeXmlFile(Document doc, String filename) {
    try {
        // Prepare the DOM document for writing
        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

        File file new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileName);

        Result result = new StreamResult(file);

        // Write the DOM document to the file
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
         // handle exception
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
         // handle exception
    }
}
```